# Duplicate copy of ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

I run the Ubuntu software three separate times because I couldn't get my computer to boot  after I finished the installation. I finally get it to work after running boot-repair but I think I have three copy of the software on my computer. How do I uninstall the two extra copies

Comment: What are the three different options called? It's normal to have `Ubuntu`, `Advanced options for Ubuntu`, `memtest` and others.

Comment: it says Ubuntu 13.10 (13.10), Advance option 13.10 (13.10), but it says that three separate times

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have 1 HDD and at least 3 partitions with 3 seperate installations of Ubuntu. Deleting the installation should be easy: Just delete the partitions that you don't want anymore and probably resize your root or home partition.

Of course you need to know which partitions are safe to delete. When you use [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) currently mounted partitions are shown as locked and need to be unmounted first before they can be deleted. Which brings us to the `mount` command. You can use `mount` to display which device (like an HDD or partition of an HDD) is mounted to which location in your operating system filesystem.

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,discard)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
```

In this case partition `/dev/sda1` is the root filesystem (`/`) of the currently running operating system, and we don't want to delete that. So the other partitions *containing Ubuntu/Linux installations* can be considered as safe to delete.

You should look at the filesystems (mount them in nautilus) and check twice before you delete the partitions with GParted. (May be check or backup the home folder first?)

I do not recommend to use only device names for making such a decision, instead you should compare filesystem UUIDs from your `/etc/fstab` instead.

To clean up your GRUB configuration you just run `sudo update-grub`.